# A Windows SSH client that isn't ugly

Tags: windows, ssh

I know of PuTTY, but let's face it, PuTTY looks bad.
Macs have some beautiful SSH clients. What about Windows? Anything stylish and modern?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of a beautiful SSH client?

Comment: A terminal is a terminal. An ssh client must be IMHO as inobtrusive as possible to get the work done.

Comment: This is a great and fun question, but rather broad, and without much research or details. Please include some more details on your requirements and what you'd consider "beautiful", add some additional requirements (surely you want a *full* ssh client? etc), include software you've tried and why you didn't like it, etc.

Comment: FLOSS or non FLOSS?

Comment: Putty can look nice if you tweak it, use a font like consolas and do some registry hacks to put in better colors quicker: http://arcanesanctum.net/2012/11/17/a-better-terminal-color-theme-for-putty/

Answer (score 5):

Beauty is in the eye of the beholder, but [ZOC Terminal](http://ssh-client.com/) should definitely be on your list.

It's not free, but chock-full of features and definitely good looking, as can be seen here.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the first answer focusing on the problem of the OP by providing a SSH client and not a SCP client. Keep up the good work

Comment: Thanks mate, much appreciated (I was wondering about the other answers myself).

Answer (score 4):

What is beautiful? Functionality or looks?

And is the emulator (wrapper) you want to look good, or the shell/environment? In most cases the environment can look great by just switching to a [Powerline font](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) variant and a customized framework ([Oh-My-Zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/), anyone?)

Here are a few of the terminal emulators I use on Windows.

---

### Hyper.is

[Hyper.is](https://hyper.is) is one of the nicest looking on windows, due to both its flexibility and customization.

Combined with ZSH (oh-my-zsh), a powerline font, a theme and some plugins, it's one of the nicer looking terminals. It's a wrapper so you can use an environment of your choice (WSL, Cygwin, msys2, Git Bash, etc). In my screenshot, I have it running in my Babun/Cygwin environment with the Material theme. Check out [Awesome-Hyper](https://github.com/bnb/awesome-hyper) to get it just the way you like.

[image: Hyper.is]

---

### Babun / Mintty

[Babun](http://babun.github.io/) is a built-for-Windows shell including must of what you need in a nice package. It's default terminal emulator is Mintty in the cygwin environment. What makes mintty nice is it's customization but a minimal approach.

[image: Babun in Mintty]

---

### Honorable Mentions

XShell 6 (beta) is shaping up nicely, although a paid solution. Mentioned for it's functionality, rather than customization.

RoyalTS is a major all-in-one tool and has everything from RDP, SSH, VNC, Telnet, etc. The free version is limited to loading a document with 10 connections; More than enough for the average user, plus you can just make multiple documents and switch between them.

WinSSHTerm, as mentioned above. Has a nice 'clean' interface with a nice layout.

Answer (score 2):

Bitvise SSH Client looks a bit more appealing than PuTTY - I used to use PuTTY but switched to this because of the interface, but as the comments say, what do **you** think "beautiful" is?

This is [Bitvise SSH Client:](http://www.bitvise.com/index)

[image: As you can see, it looks slightly better than PuTTY]

As you can see, it looks slightly better than PuTTY, almost like [Fugu for Mac](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fugussh/files/) - you might have seen it around.

It's free for individual use - hope you like it!

Comment: The screenshot seems to show an SCP GUI rather that a SSH GUI. Where can you enter terminal commands?

Comment: @ThomasWeller sorry for such a late reply, but you need to click the `New terminal console` button in the panel on the left of the screen which comes after you login to a server. [Here's a screenshot](https://www.bitvise.com/files/BvSshClient-RemoteDesktop.png) from their site :)

Comment: Neither does that screenshot show how the terminal itself looks.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are thinking about the terminal color and font, then yes the standard settings in PuTTY are not optimal - especially if you need to work with it 8 hours a day.

In [WinSSHTerm](http://www.winsshterm.net/), which is a wrapper for PuTTY, these settings are optimized for readability.

[image: WinSSHTerm]

Answer (score 1):

[Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.io/) is a free and open-source FTP, SFTP, WebDAV, S3 & OpenStack Swift file browser for Mac and Windows.

[image: Cyberduck screenshot]

Note that this is only a file browser, if you're looking for a terminal there's no such thing as a "beautiful" terminal, but you can still try [PuTTYTray](https://puttytray.goeswhere.com/) which adds some good-looking features like transparency and support for changing the taskbar icon of the terminal window, and you can use a custom color scheme, I personally use GDvalle's [Monokai](https://gist.github.com/GDvalle/4187089) theme (compatible with both PuTTYTray and the original PuTTY, just save the Gist as a `.reg` file and open it).

Here's what PuTTYTray looks like on my machine with the Monokai theme, cleartype font, transparency and a custom icon :

[image: PuTTYTray screenshot]

Comment: it seems putty tray also makes the text transparent.  is there a way to keep the text opaque only background transparent?

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorite ssh clients is [Termius](https://www.termius.com/), previously known as Serverauditor. It's very beautiful and works very good in smartphones too.

> Termius is the #1 cross-platform terminal with built-in SSH and
>   Telnet. It is the portable server management system that works for you
>   in any situation.

[image: termius ssh]

Comment: How do I use this to connect with a key file instead of username and password? Could not figure it out. Either not possible or usability is below 0.

Comment: @ThomasWeller couldn't find how do that too. They claim that they provide password, key and 2FA (multi-factor) authentication, but it seems that in windows version this feature is not yet included. My mistake not paying attention to this, sorry.

Comment: @ThomasWeller you just go to the keychaing and manually paste the private key, then assign it to a host,

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell team from Microsoft [ported OpenSSH to Windows](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH). It doesn't provide a graphic user interface but that's advantage to me, because I have been running PowerShell within [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) for long. This is a screenshot from ConEmu website:

[image: ConEmu]

Coming from Linux, I always like the idea of separating Virtual Terminal (like iTerm2 in macOS) from Shell and Application (like Bash and SSH), because I typically want to configure them independently. "Tabs within window" is obviously the job of a terminal, so it is weird to ask SSH client to do that.